# Scala Execute Shell file

Tags: scala, shell, gatling

I have a .sh file in which I want to run in Scala once a Gatling scenario has finished.

Does anyone have any code that would execute my sh script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the after block provided by Gattling :-

Refer this : https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/simulation_structure/#hooks

Here you can use after block :-

```
after {  println("Simulation is finished!")}
```

Rest all is pure scala so use @Andrey answer above